# How to do a post request and save data to the db using django-tastypie?

Tags: django, tastypie

so, I was building rest APIs for the first time using django-tasty-pie. I'm stuck at a basic issue which deals with posting data to the localserver that saves it to the db. How do I do that?

How do I send a post request that gets the data out of the request and saves it to the db?

Unfortunately, there isn't much on POST/PUT in the django-tasty-pie documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page helped me a lot

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html